# external link of navbar in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Just now, I tried what add link to navbar. for example;

```
menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Test', 'url' => ['http://www.google.com']];
```

But i saw, any time yii2 is adding baseUrl to per address. i did this too;

File: \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php

Before:

```
public static function a($text, $url = null, $options = [])
    {
        if ($url !== null) {
            $options['href'] = Url::to($url);
        }
        return static::tag('a', $text, $options);
    }
```

After:

```
public static function a($text, $url = null, $options = [])
        {
            if ($url !== null) {
                $options['href'] = Url::to($url,'http');
            }
            return static::tag('a', $text, $options);
        }
```

it's working this, but i don't know, is it true? What do you think?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for external link just use raw string format:

```
menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Test', 'url' => 'http://www.google.com'];
```

Comment: I understand now :) that's it. I changed again

Answer (score 3):

this work without raw format
`$menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Test', 'url'=>null, 'linkOptions'=>['href'=>'http://www.google.com']];`